# What resolution should I choose by default for a created image that might go to print?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, printing, dpi

I've been creating images for a long time in Photoshop, but it just suddenly dawned on me that I might need to actually print some of my creations and that 72DPI probably wouldn't cut it. What is a good DPI/resolution for print? Most of the design I've done before has been for web, so it's worked out, but if I ever have to go to print, it'd be nice to do so without having to upsample the image. Is 300DPI a good all-around DPI for an image that will be used on the web and for print?

Comment: i think the people at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ should know that, maybe you should ask it there. Also include how professional you work and how good your printer is. I would go for 300pix/inch but I'm no pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If space is not a large issue, just save in the highest quality that you will ever need to print in. Downsampling is much easier than upsampling.

> Printer settings of 360dpi, 720dpi, 1440dpi and 2880dpi are often found. However the difference between then is subtle at best. Most people probably couldn't tell the difference and 360dpi usually looks great. Changing DPI does not change the size of the print. ppi controls that. dpi controls print quality (though as I said, over 360dpi you typically don't see much change).

[Source](http://photo.net/learn/resize/)

Comment: 600DPI should be more than enough, right?

Comment: Edited answer, but 600 sounds fine.